# How do I remove a duplicate repository

Tags: git

I have a duplicate of my repository as a sub directory of that repo on my remote GitHub. It is not being tracked in my commits. How do I remove it?

Comment: You should describe your problem in more detail, perhaps with a link to the repository given that it is (presumably as it is on github) public. As is, it is difficult to understand exactly what your issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a "duplicate of a repository inside of itself". I guess that you accidentally cloned the repository for the second time into the subfolder of the first clone, and then you accidentally added all files and made a commit. That's ok, you can do with this commit whatever you do with any other one. If you know how to change the history (`git rebase --interactive`) you may remove this erroneous commit completely (with care cause interactive rebase is a dangerous tool). If this is the last commit done you may try `git commit --amend` to change it. Or you may reset the branch to a valid commit, leaving the erroneous commit detached and wait for the garbage collector to remove it from disk.